# I can't open file in C

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, binary-search-tree

When executed my code in Codeblocks , there is a problem like "error opening file" and I'm sure that there is a file as named "Names". Should I transport my .txt file to another file or something?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
  char *word;
  int count;
  struct node *left;
  struct node *right;
};

// Function to create a new node
struct node* createNode(char *word) {
  struct node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  newNode->word = strdup(word);
  newNode->count = 1;
  newNode->left = NULL;
  newNode->right = NULL;
  return newNode;
}

// Function to insert a new node into the binary search tree
struct node* insert(struct node *root, char *word) {
  if (root == NULL) {
    // Create a new node if the tree is empty
    return createNode(word);
  } else if (strcmp(word, root->word) < 0) {
    // Insert the word in the left subtree if it is less than the root node's word
    root->left = insert(root->left, word);
  } else if (strcmp(word, root->word) > 0) {
    // Insert the word in the right subtree if it is greater than the root node's word
    root->right = insert(root->right, word);
  }
  // Increment the count if the word already exists in the tree
  else {
    root->count++;
  }
  return root;
}

// Function to find the depth of the binary search tree
int findDepth(struct node *root) {
  if (root == NULL) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    // Calculate the depth of the left and right subtrees
    int leftDepth = findDepth(root->left);
    int rightDepth = findDepth(root->right);
    // Return the maximum of the left and right depths
    if (leftDepth > rightDepth) {
      return leftDepth + 1;
    } else {
      return rightDepth + 1;
    }
  }
}

// Function to count the number of nodes in the binary search tree
int main() {
  // Open the text file for reading
  FILE *file = fopen("C:\C\Names.txt", "r");
  if (file == NULL) {
    printf("Error opening file\n");
    return 1;
  }

  // Initialize the root node to NULL
  struct node *root = NULL;
  char word[50];
  int wordCount = 0;
  // Read each word from the file and add it to the tree
  while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF) {
    root = insert(root, word);
    wordCount++;
  }
  static int count = 0;
  int countnodes(struct node *root) {
    if (root != NULL) {
      countnodes(root->left);
      count++;
      countnodes(root->right);
    }
    return count;

  }
  // Close the file
  fclose(file);
  printf(
      "In total %d words were read from the file and saved in the binary search tree.\n",
      wordCount);
  printf("Number of nodes in the binary search tree: %d\n", countnodes(root));
  printf("The depth of the binary search tree: %d\n", findDepth(root));
}
```

I tried to change my opening text codeblocks with another codes from internet. But it doesn't work again.

Comment: You need to add double backslashes like "C:\\C\\Names.txt"

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you cannot open the file, there is no need to include all the list handling. That is only disctracting readers from your main issue. Take a look at [How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/mcve).

Comment: `fscanf(file, "%s", word)` risks overflow.  Better as `fscanf(file, "%49s", word)`.

Comment: [Here's how to ask a proper "Where's the bug / Fix my code" question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/11107541). Can you please read it and apply what you learn to improve your question?

Answer (score 1):

Your filepath should be written as `"C:\\C\\Names.txt"` or `"C:/C/Names.txt"`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `fopen("C:\C\Names.txt", "r")` should instead be `fopen("C:\\C\\Names.txt", "r")`.

In the C language, the backslash character has a special meaning in string literals: It is used as an "escape character" to allow representing some common characters that are not found on most keyboards. A list of escape sequences can be found [here on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/escape).

Taking a look at that list on cppreference, you'll see that to enter a single literal backslash in the interpreted value of a string literal, you must put two consecutive backslash characters in the source-code for the string literal, like "`\\`". The first one begins the "escape sequence", and the second one specifies that the escape sequence represents a literal backslash character.

Curiously, cppreference says that:

> ISO C requires a diagnostic if the backslash is followed by any character not listed here

And your `\C` and `\N` are not in the list, so for your compiler to not have warned you, I'm guessing it must have been in a non-ISO-compliant mode, in which case you can search your compiler's documentation to see how to switch to an ISO-compliant mode.